# Is Codeschool.com recommended in addition to Lynda.com?

Tags: learning

Does Codeschool's ability to perform activity / test / game / training as their approach, offer something that achieve studying faster and more effectively than Lynda.com's exercise file / video structure doesn't.

Comment: May I ask why my question is being downvoted?

Comment: I think asking recommendations is not allowed, do check the do's and don'ts in the faq section. Although I wouldn't blame you :-)

Comment: Your question is being down voted because it does not fit Stack Exchange in regards to an EXACT answer.  Your question causes biased solutions and can change over time.  If you go to faq your comment will also be answered on what is preferred here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just learn from one source, learn from as many as you can (or have time to). It will make you more well rounded.

My first recommendation is [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) as a brilliant free resource but there are other paid for ones like [Treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com).

Comment: Lovely advice and I wasn't aware that Codeacademy was free so thank you Len.